# What does the colon (:) do in this code do?

Tags: python-3.x

I accidentally used `:` instead of `=` when assigning a variable, and I was surprised that it didn't generate an error. For example, the following runs without complaints:

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Jul  9 2019, 18:15:00)
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a: 'hello world'
>>>
```

However, this doesn't seem to actually do anything. I've tried looking in the documentation and tutorials, I only find [compound statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html), [dict comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and [sequence slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations), and I can't see how either of those apply in this case.

For comparison, in Python 2.7 it *does* generate a syntax error:

```
Python 2.7.16 (default, Apr 12 2019, 15:32:52)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a: 'hello world'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a: 'hello world'
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why does this not cause a syntax error in Python 3.7, and what (if anything) could it be used for?

Comment: I would say it is a type hint.

Comment: It is a variable annotation as used for type hinting. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recent versions of Python support a syntax known as type hinting, or type annotations. This syntax lets you write `a: int` to declare that in the current context the variable `a` will have the type `int`.

The compiler doesn't actually check that and in fact will allow any expression after the variable name so the string you used will be accepted as a valid type hint.

See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/ for a detailed description of type hints.

If you do add type hints to your code then you can use a tool such as [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) so perform static type checking.

Comment: I forgot about type hints, but even so would have expected the compiler to catch obvious garbage, thanks for the explanation!