# Specific syntax in python explanation

Tags: python

I was reading some python code and I came across a method that I don't understand and struggle to find the meaning of it.

Here it is :

```
def packages(self) -> Set[str]:
    packages: Set[str] = set()
    files = [a_file for a_file in glob.glob("{}/*.properties".format(self._app_dir))
             if not a_file.endswith(".properties")
             and os.path.exists(a_file)
             and os.path.isfile(a_file)
             and os.access(a_file, R_OK)]
    for a_file in files:
        file_name = os.path.basename(a_file)
        package_name = self._remove_extension(file_name)
        packages.add(package_name)
    return set(packages)
```

Also when I'm importing the module containing this method in a python interpreter it will throw an error pointing the ":" on the line:

> packages: Set[str] = Set()

What does it mean ?

Comment: `packages: Set[str] = set()` initialize an empty set and assign it to `packages` variable, `Set[str]` part specify that it should be set of strings.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html for more information on type hints.

Comment: It's [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) notation.

Comment: Yeah ok it's just explicitly precing the type then, any idea why the interpreter would fail on it ?

Comment: If it throws an error, you're either missing an import (`import typing.Set` or something like that; but with the line above it not failing, `Set` doesn't seem to be the problem), or use a too old Python interpreter.

Comment: @OlvinRoght is right. There's a couple of odd things here though that you might want to watch out for. First, naming a variable the same as the function isn't recommended (no kind of shadowing is recommended usually) and possibly indicates this was written by someone more used to a language where that's how you return a value. Second, the `packages` variable is created as a set and then used to initialise another set that is returned. That doesn't achieve anything other than a minor waste of cycles and it could just be `return packages`.

Comment: Would python 3.5.2 be too old for this ? I indeed have a Syntax error

Comment: @9769953, `from typing import Set`

Comment: Yeah, 3.5 would be too old for current typing hints. It probably doesn't recognise the list `[str]` convention. That's more 3.8 or 3.9, I think.

Comment: 3.5 is past its end of life anyway (and 3.6 only a few months from eof).

Comment: @RobertReynolds, feature you're trying to use have been added at version `3.6` and described in [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/). Basic typing support have been added at version `3.5`, look [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/).

Comment: looks like a duplicate of this question: [What does the colon (:) do in this code do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57959461/what-does-the-colon-do-in-this-code-do)